# angularjs converting json object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hi I have json return object like this

```
color_selected = [
                { id: 4}, 
                { id: 3} 
    ];
```

how do I convert it to

```
color_selected = [4,3]
```

thank you for your any help and suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate through it like this:

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < color_selected.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(color_selected[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use javascript `map` function for that

```
var newArray = color_selected.map(o=> o.id)
```

```js
var color_selected = [
                { id: 4}, 
                { id: 3} 
    ];
 var newArray = color_selected.map(o=> o.id)
 console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: working fine var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < color_selected.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(color_selected[i].id);
} this is also fine

Comment: @sanu javascript `map` is functional programming method. it's better if you can follow array method

Comment: This is certainly a good solution, but it's worth noting that lambda expressions require ES6

Answer (score 1):

```
color_selected = [
            { id: 4}, 
            { id: 3} 
];
```

You can use lodash

// in 3.10.1

```
_.pluck(color_selected, 'id'); // → [4, 3]
_.map(color_selected, 'id'); // → [4, 3]
```

// in 4.0.0

```
_.map(color_selected, 'id'); // → [4, 3]
```

Comment: This is also a good solution, but is it worth bringing another library into your solution _just_ to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) method with `ES6` Arrow operator.

```js
var color_selected = [
                { id: 4}, 
                { id: 3} 
    ];
    
color_selected = color_selected.map(item => {return item.id });

console.log(color_selected);
```